# ConscryptEngine data read issue : Unable to parse TLS packet header

Tags: android, socketchannel, tcpsocket, sslengine, openssl-engine

Below i the code for unwrap the data packets received from sslengine :

```
private ByteBuffer doUnwrap() throws IOException {
        if (mPeerNetData.position() == 0) {
            // The network input buffer is empty; read data from the channel before doing the unwrap
            final int count = mSocketChannel.read(mPeerNetData);
            Log.d(TAG, "bytesRead : " + count);
            if (count == -1) {
                handleEndOfStream(mSocketChannel, mSslEngine);
                return null;
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "isReadPending :" + isReadPending);
        if (!isReadPending) {
            mPeerNetData.flip();
        }

        final SSLEngineResult result;
        try {
            result = mSslEngine.unwrap(mPeerNetData, mPeerAppData);
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception while calling SSLEngine.unwrap()" + e);
            shutdown();
            return null;
        }
        mPeerNetData.compact();
        Log.d(TAG, "Result of SSLEngine.unwrap(): {}" + result.getStatus());


        final SSLEngineResult.Status status = result.getStatus();
        switch (status) {
            case OK:
                if (mPeerNetData.position() != 0) {
                    isReadPending = true;
                    mPeerAppData = ensureRemaining(mPeerAppData, mSslEngine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize());
                    doUnwrap();
                }
                break;

            case CLOSED:
                closeConnection(mSocketChannel, mSslEngine);
                break;

            case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                // The network input buffer might not have enough space, re-allocate if necessary
                // (NOTE: packet buffer size as reported by the SSL session might change dynamically)
                mPeerNetData = ensureRemaining(mPeerNetData, mSslEngine.getSession().getPacketBufferSize());

                // Read data from the channel, retry unwrap if not end-of-stream
                final int count = mSocketChannel.read(mPeerNetData);
                if (count == -1) {
                    handleEndOfStream(mSocketChannel, mSslEngine);
                    return null;
                }
                doUnwrap();
                break;

            case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                // The application input buffer does not have enough space, re-allocate and retry unwrap
                // (NOTE: application buffer size as reported by the SSL session might change dynamically)
                mPeerAppData = ensureRemaining(mPeerAppData, mSslEngine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize());
                doUnwrap();
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid SSL status: " + status);
        }

        return mPeerAppData;
    }
```

mPeerNetData buffer has some data remains to read during unwrap and therefor i have enlarged the mPeerAppData buffer to hold the more data that has to be read from mPeerNetData buffer in next iteration.

I have debugged the flow  and can verify that mPeerAppData buffer has sufficient space to hold the data and also mPeerNetData buffer has data pending to be unwrap.

But during unwrap i am getting the error has below :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to parse TLS packet header
at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:798)
at org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:738)
```

Please suggest how we can avoid this error ?

Comment: I wonder if this has any relation to https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/825 and https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/issues/553.

Comment: @David no, it was the issue with the way we were reading the data. see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

After spending few days and debugging the code , i was able to know the root cause of this issue.

Above codes start working fine after i figured out that during the below operation

```
result = mSslEngine.unwrap(mPeerNetData, mPeerAppData);
```

where `mPeerNetData` is buffer containing the encrypted bytes read from `socketChannel` and `mPeerAppData` is a buffer holding the decrypted bytes after `unwrap` operation.

After the unwrap operation successfully decrypt a packet from `mPeerNetData`, there were still some bytes left and were not sufficient to perform `unwrap` action again. To do further `unwrap` operation , we need to read more data from `socketChannel` again but keep in mind we should not clear the `mPeerNetData` instead we should add the new data to `mPeerNetData` which has some bytes left previously.

Those previous left bytes are must to have in buffer for success-full decryption of data because each unwrap tries to read some initial bytes from the packet.In that way during next unwrap operation the action will success-full.

Also please note that to read complete `socketChannel` data you should have some `while loop` logic to invoke this method until you read the complete data from channel.

Comment: Hi Ashok, can you also explain how did you solve this issue,